# UTF-8 conversion unknown-8bit

Tags: php, bash, csv, utf-8

When I run this bash script manually the file Ref.csv is converted into UTF-8.

> csv/itm/Ref.csv: text/plain; charset=utf-8

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -v OFS=";" '
FNR==1  { a[1]=a[1] (a[1]==""?"":OFS) $0; next } 
FNR==NR { a[NR]=$0 OFS 0 OFS 0; next } 
        { a[NR]=0 OFS 0 OFS $0 } 
END     { for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)if(i in a)print a[i] }
' csv/Liste_EAN.csv csv/Liste_PDV.csv >> csv/itm/Ref_f.csv;
cat csv/itm/Ref_f.csv | awk 'BEGIN{ FS=" *;"; OFS=";" } {$1=$1; print $0}' >> csv/itm/Ref_n.csv;
iconv --from-code=ISO-8859-1 --to-code=UTF-8 csv/itm/Ref_n.csv > csv/itm/Ref.csv;
rm csv/itm/Ref_f.csv;
rm csv/itm/Ref_n.csv;
```

But when I run it using php shellexec, the file isn't converted correctly.

```
shell_exec('./script.sh');
```

> csv/itm/Ref.csv: text/plain; charset=unknown-8bit

How do I fix this error?

Comment: You have a file encoded in utf8, then you call iconv to convert it from latin1 to utf8.

Comment: No, when I run the script manually from the terminal, the file is converted to UTF-8 without any problem. But when I run this script through phpexec, the result is unknown-8bit.

Comment: Sorry, my wrong. I misread the data.